# Drawing chart freezes GUI

Tags: c#, async-await

Hello I have the following code:

```
    private void FormEKG_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
       InitializeChartEKG();
       RunParser();
    }
    
    private async void RunParser () {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(FillChartEKG); //long running process 
        CallBack();
    }
    
    private async void CallBack() {
        DrawChartEKG(parsedEKGData, counter, loopToStopAt);
    }

    private void DrawChartEKG  (List<AnesthParsedEKGData> parsedEKGData, int counter, int loopToStopAt) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parsedEKGData.Count; i++) {
                series1.Points.AddXY(parsedEKGData[i].TimeStamp, 
        parsedEKGData[i].Point);
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = counter * 500;
chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum - Convert.ToDouble(loopToStopAt));
}
```

The long running process runs like a charm with no GUI freezing. But the GUI will freeze for about 20 seconds when drawing the chart. How can I change my code to fix the freeze?

Incidentally, if I make the following changes to the code, it will run without a freeze.

```
        private async void DrawChartEKG (List<AnesthParsedEKGData> parsedEKGData, int counter, int loopToStopAt) {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
            for (int i = 0; i < parsedEKGData.Count; i++) {

                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                series1.Points.AddXY(parsedEKGData[i].TimeStamp, parsedEKGData[i].Point)));
            }
        });
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = counter * 500; //);
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum - Convert.ToDouble(loopToStopAt)); 

    }
```

But then the chart will draw a point at time (like a live EKG in real time) which would take over an hour to display, since my test case is about an hour long. I want to display the entire case at once (when I say 'at once' it's about 20 seconds, which is how long the GUI freezes for to draw the chart). Hope that's clear. Thanks.

PS: Here is the chart initialization code for @Xerillo:

```
        private void InitializeChartEKG () {
        series1 = new Series {
            Color = Color.LawnGreen,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine
        };
        chartEKG.Series.Clear();
        chartEKG.Series.Add(series1);
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Time";
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = true;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineColor = Color.LawnGreen;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.LineColor = Color.LawnGreen;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 100;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;  
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = true;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1000;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -600;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 10000;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "mV";
        chartEKG.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chartEKG.Series[0].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss tt";
        chartArea = chartEKG.ChartAreas[0];
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
        int position = 0;
        int blockSize = 10000;
        int size = blockSize;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(position, size);
        //chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(200, 200);
        chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chartEKG.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = blockSize;
        chartArea.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.LineColor = Color.DarkBlue;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 20;
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    }
```

Comment: How many datapoints do you end up adding to the chart?  Which charting library are you using?

Comment: There's some lacking context here. What type of application is this? What's `series1`, `chartEKG`? How many items does `parsedEKGData` contain and is whatever `chartEKG` is, built to support that amount of data points?

Comment: @Ben Voight - for this test patient, it's roughly 277,000. The data is coming from a vital sign monitor, which outputs 500 data points every second (500 data points is equivalent to 1 complete EKG waveform (P, QRS and T). Charting library is DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: @Xerillo - App is a Winforms app. I'll post the chart initialization code is a sec.

Comment: Given that the [`Points` collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection?view=netframework-4.8.1) only allows for inserting one point at a time, I doubt this component is meant for such a huge amount of data points. I'd recommend either cutting down on the amount (for plotting, 277K seems crazy excessive) or find a library with a chart component that supports this.

Comment: I uploaded a couple of videos to show the output I want https://youtu.be/bIx-UH46juw (GUI freezes) vs what the output is with no freezing:  https://youtu.be/cmb85k0dr6U

Comment: Looks like LightningCharts is what I need: https://lightningchart.com/net-charts/. Thanks

Comment: @WilliamJ.Starck Aside from the assumption of 60bpm, that makes sense.  It does sound like you need to pick a better charting solution, or if using the Microsoft DataVisualization one, reduce the amount of data you give to it at a time.  Remember that very very few computer monitors have more than 3840 pixels across.